# Bootstrap 3.0 RC1 compatible datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Start learning Bootstrap. I'm writing a site prototype for my work, and I need a datepicker component. Someone knows a component that is compatible with the new version of Bootstrap, 3.0 RC1? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I found a viable BS3 datepicker component [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker); it's a WIP but that's acceptable as I'm in the prototype phase of my project. I hope someone could find this helpful.

<del>Btw this component isn't still listed in the gallery of Bootstrap components, [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/resources#5).</del>

**EDIT** - This component is now listed at [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/resources#5)

**EDIT** - This is compatible with the latest stable version of BS3.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed compatible with BS3. Tested and verified.
One Important thing to mention is that the libraries have to be linked in the order specified on the website.

1- jQuery
2- moment js
3- bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
4- bootstrap-datetimepicker.css
5- bootstrap.min.js
6- bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard and well know jquery Ui datepicker, it is well documented
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
this works fine with bootstrap since this comes naturally with jquery-ui.min.js
You can use it simply by puting this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.date').datepicker({ //Your options here });
)};
```

with `<input class="date" />`

**Edit**

BootStrap Has it's own datePicker https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker this is if you want to use a common layout

Comment: My concern with this component is to maintain a uniform style with bootstrap. But I just learned that those jquery ui components use a specific stylesheet that can be customized.

Comment: If you want to use a common style in your web site, bootstrap introduced a datepicker itself http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ you can check it out https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: I saw those, but still don't work with Bootstrap 3 (there are changes in the styles).

Comment: @HamdiBaligh, although issues are _supposed_ to be resolved between jquery-ui and bootstrap, I still find it an issue to work with both alongside each other. Plus, it seems a little overkill to add an entire new ui framework to accomplish this. I'm still looking for an answer to this too...